# How to use a resource value to control a view's visibility?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Button widget that appears in multiple layouts. Eventually in the final release, the button will be hidden from the user, but until then I need it to be visible for the alpha and beta phases of development.

Is there a way to control the visibility for that button from an unique resource value?

Something like this:

```
<!-- Feedback button -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/feedback"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/buttons_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/buttons_margin"
    android:text="Feedback"
    android:visibility="<some resource value>"
    />
```

An alternative would be to have a boolean value, and set the Button's visibility programmatically, but it would have to be done in every single activity that this button in its layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible:

```
android:visibility="@integer/show_view"
```

And in your `integers.xml`-file:

```
<integer name="show_view">0</string>
```

The possible values are

```
0 (VISIBLE)
1 (INVISIBLE)
2 (GONE)
```

Comment: Ummm... are you sure that string resources are the correct approach here? Usually, these need to be integer resources, with the numeric value underlying the symbolic name.

Comment: I've just tested it and it seems to work (in the layout editor, at least). Creating an int resource with the value of the respective constants would probably work, as well.

Comment: I'm getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "gone"` at the line `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);`

Comment: Then it seems CommonsWare was correct. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Miraduro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7874326/miraduro)'s answer, you can add `integers.xml` entries for all the `View` visibility options:

```
    <!--  View visibilities  -->
    <integer name="visible">0</integer>
    <integer name="invisible">1</integer>
    <integer name="gone">2</integer>
```

and then reference them like this:

```
    <integer name="visibility_user_profile_item">@integer/visible</integer>
```

This will make it easier for other team members to understand what you're doing.